# Adding delays to bookmarklet to allow for opening multiple variable urls

Tags: javascript, url, bookmarklet

First time asker long time learner.
I am trying to make a bookmarklet (could use something else if suggested) that where highlighted text is added to specific urls to open multiple urls eg google.com/xxx and gmail.com/search/xxx the below works for one launch however with chromes popup blocker i cannot get multiple urls to load, or my code is wrong. Disabling adblock is not an option.

...

Javascript:(function(){s=document.selection?document.selection.createRange().text:window.getSelection?window.getSelection().toString():document.getSelection?document.getSelection():'';if(s==''){s=prompt('You%20did%20not%20select%20any%20text%20to%20search%20for.%20Enter%20the%20text%20to%20search%20for%20:','');}if(s){window.open('https://url1.com/'+s,  '_blank')};})()

...
I was thinking to add multiple urls with a delay

...
Javascript:(function(){s=document.selection?document.selection.createRange().text:window.getSelection?window.getSelection().toString():document.getSelection?document.getSelection():'';if(s==''){s=prompt('You%20did%20not%20select%20any%20text%20to%20search%20for.%20Enter%20the%20text%20to%20search%20for%20:','');}if(s){
window.open('https://url1.com/'+s,  '_blank')
delay(10)
window.open('https://url2.com/'+s,  '_blank')
};})()
...

but cannot get this to work. any assistance would be great and i would happy to support patreon etc.
TIA

- I have tried to get to learn to put the code in propper format im sure the first comment will tell me how. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In general, you have paraphrased your question, and you have got an answer:
[Bookmarklet to open multiple urls not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61903024/bookmarklet-to-open-multiple-urls-not-working/64581829#64581829)

But, to sum up, several important things here, just for your information:

1 - `window.getSelection().toString();` to retrieve text selected.

2 - Bookmarklet as a browser bookmark with a js-code looks like this:

```
javascript:(function () {
    /*code is put here*/
})();`
```

3 - Instead of delay `setTimeout`, for example

```
setTimeout(function(){
    window.open('https://www.google.com/'+'text'), 3000);
}
```