# Bookmarklet to open multiple urls not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bookmarklet

ive been working on the below for a while. It should work i think... but wont. i know i will have to disable chromes adblock on whatever page i run it on but i cant see where ive gone wrong. Its intended use is to highlight text then run bookmarklet which will open 4 urls using that text at the end of the url. any help is greatly appreciated. 
'''

```
    s=document.selection?document.selection.createRange().text:window.getSelection?window.getSelection().toString():document.getSelection?document.getSelection():'';
    if(s==''){
        s=prompt(''You%20did%20not%20select%20any%20text%20to%20search%20for.%20Enter%20the%20text%20to%20search%20for%20:','');
    }
    if(s)
    { 
        window.open("https://www.google.com/"+s);   
        setTimeout(function(){
            window.open('https://youtube.com/'+s,"_blank");
        }, 3000);
        setTimeout(function(){
            window.open('https://url3.com/'+s,"_blank");
        }, 9000);
        setTimeout(function(){
            window.open('https://url4.com/'+s,"_blank");
        }, 12000);
    };
```

New Text Document.txt
Displaying with new windows.txt. 
'''

Answer (score 0):

So in a general way of retrieving selected text is `window.getSelection().toString();`

It looks like you have almost made it yourself.
However, it seems like your third line has a minor **mistype, an extra single quotation mark**, right after prompt and an opening bracket; after the fix the code starts working.

Anyway, several **more tweaks** to make the code even better:

- Prompt text as plain text, without escaping spaces etc.
- It is better not to use global variables, like `s`; therefore, it might be better to have at least `var s`.
- A bit formatting (spaces after `=`, single quotation marks everywhere instead of double quotes to make uniform code)

A modified version:

```
var s = document.selection?document.selection.createRange().text:window.getSelection?window.getSelection().toString():document.getSelection?document.getSelection():'';
if(s == ''){
    s = prompt('You did not select any text to search. Enter the text to search for.','');
}
if(s)
{ 
    window.open('https://www.google.com/'+s);   
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.open('https://youtube.com/'+s,'_blank');
    }, 3000);
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.open('https://url3.com/'+s,'_blank');
    }, 9000);
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.open('https://url4.com/'+s,'_blank');
    }, 12000);
};
```

And, by the way, if you want to make it as a bookmarklet, as it is in your tag, then your code should be inside this and saved as a **bookmarklet** (a browser **bookmark** with js-code):

```
javascript:(function () {
    /*code above here*/
})();
```